# How to forward http to https with Lightsail Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I currently have an app built on a lightsail server.
I used Amazon certificate to create SSL https with a load balancer.
Under inbound traffic I have to protocols

```
Http Enabled
Https Enabled.
```

When I go to https://app.myexample.com sure enough I get an SSL certificate all good.
However I'd like to forward http to https.  When you go to http://app.myexample.com you get no secure connection (obviously).  How can I force http to go to https?

I was going to do it with an .htaccess file but I read somewhere that it should be done through the Load Balancer.  Unfortunately all documentation for this is only for Elastic Beanstalk.  I'm using Lightsail.  How can I accomplish this on lightsail?
[image]

Comment: I've encountered the same situation. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't yet @Ruslan

Comment: I have managed to do so only with the the full-blown (non-lightsail) EC2 ELB where listeners are supported https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it on Lighsail services level, but!
AWS load balancer pass http_x_forwarded_proto header further.
It is possible to do redirect on your app, webserver level.
I'm using nginx web server, there this configuration looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    }
       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/#step-4-modify-the-web-server-configuration-on-the-bitnami-application-instance) worked for me.

- This is an instance-level solution, so you should detach all the instances except for one.
- After all the settings have been updated, make sure to take a snapshot to use it when creating a new instance.
- This requires some file updates so you may need to use an editor such as Vim.